# Converting numbers to exponential form in R

Tags: r

I have a file where one variable is a combination of 0.00234 and 2.34e-05.. So can some one help me how to convert everything into exponential format.

Comment: You mean you want to show them as a string in the same format? There is no real difference between the number formats as far as R is concerned. Can you do `dput` on the vector and post the result?

Comment: Hi David. I was trying to subset the data, based on P-value less than 0.0001 were P-values is a combination of numbers like 0.0023 and also 2.3E-04... R considers only those that are in exponential form. It is very strange.

Comment: If you want to write to file, then you can use `format(x, scientific=TRUE)` which will convert it to string in scientific notation.

Comment: Please edit your data into your question (using the edit link), and format it as code using the button with the two curly braces (`{}`). Secondly, if your issue is about subsetting the data, it makes no difference which "format" the numbers are in. R will understand something like `dat[dat$FRQ > .01]` whether the `FRQ` variable was exponential or not when the data was read in.

Comment: @VenkateshRajamanickam, could you please delete your comment and **edit your original post** with this information? It is hard to read as such unformatted data under comments section.

Comment: @James: of course those two differ, they differ by two orders of magnitude. It has nothing to do with the exponential format. The real test would be `all.equal(0.0000234,2.34e-05)` or `all.equal(0.00234,2.34e-03)`, both of which (unsurprisingly) return TRUE.

Comment: @Arun -- You should post that as an answer.

Comment: A good answer should explain the difference between printing format and the type of a vector.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Ah yes, I didn't look too carefully there. Ignore my remark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind the change of format from `numeric` to `string` in order to view the results of your `p-values` column in scientific notation, then, use:

```
x <- c(1, .1, .01, .001, .0001)
> x
# [1] 1.0000 0.1000 0.0100 0.0010 0.0001

> format(x, scientific=TRUE) # converts to character vector/string
# [1] "1e+00" "1e-01" "1e-02" "1e-03" "1e-04"
```

Note that it has been converted to string in addition to having a scientific notation. This could be used, for example, if you're interested in writing to a file with this format (in addition to viewing the results, of course). However, in case, you would want to keep the numeric format but just want to view all values in scientific notation within R, then, you can use the solution @Josh recommended by setting `options(scipen = -10)`.

```
options(scipen = -10)
> x # numeric
# [1] 1e+00 1e-01 1e-02 1e-03 1e-04
options(scipen = 2)
> x # numeric
[1] 1.0000 0.1000 0.0100 0.0010 0.0001
```

Comment: is it possible to convert to scientific notation but retain numeric format?