# Convert a numeric vector to scientific format without changing the mode in R

Tags: r, formatting, type-conversion

I would like to convert a numeric vector into the scientific format without changing its mode to a character. The solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706677/how-to-display-numeric-columns-in-an-r-dataframe-without-scientific-notation-e) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962224/converting-numbers-to-exponential-form-in-r) changes the mode to character. I have tried the following:

```
x <- c(1.0004, 2.2223,4, 509703045845, 0.0002)
mode(x)
#first attempt
x1 <- formatC(x, format = "e")
mode(x1)
as.numeric(x1)

#second attempt
x2 <- format(x, scientific = TRUE)
mode(x2)
as.numeric(x2)
```

Conversion to numeric does not retain the scientific display. I would like a solution that changes the display to scientific but retains numeric mode.

Comment: The accepted answer does state to change `options` since it's a display issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Format` and `FormatC` are designed to obtain characters in the desired shape. Your display of numerics will not be affected. Moreover, converting to character there and back to numerics will **bias your numbers**! Consider the [first of your linked solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706677/how-to-display-numeric-columns-in-an-r-dataframe-without-scientific-notation-e) using `options()$scipen`, which is literally the only option to change the display of numbers to R. `scipen` comes from *sci*entific and *pen*alty, see `?options`.

```
x <- c(1.0004, 2.2223,4, 509703045845, 0.0002)

getOption("scipen")  ## displays defaults
# [1] 5
x
# [1] 1.00040e+00 2.22230e+00 4.00000e+00 5.09703e+11 2.00000e-04
as.numeric(format(x, scientific = TRUE))  ## convert there and back
# [1] 1.00040e+00 2.22230e+00 4.00000e+00 5.09703e+11 2.00000e-04
```

Both the same (?).

But:

```
os <- options(scipen=50)  ## set scipen and store old scipen
x
# [1]         1.0004          2.2223       4.0000     509703045845.0000    0.0002
as.numeric(format(x, scientific = TRUE))  ## convert there and back
# [1]         1.0004          2.2223       4.0000     509703045845.0000    0.0002
```

So actually nothing happens, converting there and back is **1.** a *false* solution,

```
options(os)  ## restore old scipen
```

and **2.** will **bias** your numbers as shown below:

```
all.equal(x, as.numeric(format(x, scientific = TRUE)))
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.00000008994453"
```

**Note:** `options` are reset to the default values stored in your `Rprofile.site` when you restart R, so don't panic ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there might be a function for this in some package out there, but why not just writing your own simple function?

```
to_scientific <- function(x){
  x <- format(x, scientific = TRUE)
  as.numeric(x)
}
to_scientific(x)
# [1] 1.00040e+00 2.22230e+00 4.00000e+00 5.09703e+11 2.00000e-04
```

Comment: Nice try, but this is a  _false_  solution, see my answer.